# How we can execute two post request simultaneously

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

how i can execute two post request simultaneously in Gatling

as i am unable to execute two post request simultaneously

Comment: Can you post your setup code?

Comment: What is the scenario you're trying to replicate?

Answer (score 0):

The only real support for this in gatling is the 'resources' http option which is designed to simulate how browsers fetch stuff in parallel.